# Knowing the result of SMS activity invoked by Intent.ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am using Intent.ACTION_VIEW to launch **New Message** composer for the mobile using code given below

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:"));
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address"  , numbersString); //delimited phone numbers
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body"  , Constants.SMS_DEFAULT_MESSAGE); //actual message

startActivity(smsIntent);
```

This correctly starts activity that launches the **New Message** composer. However, I want to know whether the User went ahead and actually sent the message, or did he cancel the sending of message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried **startActivityForResult**() ?
As per Android Documentation, it is typically used for below purpose:

Launch an activity for which you would like a result when it finished. When this activity exits, your onActivityResult() method will be called with the given requestCode.

That means you need to implement  onActivityResult() callback in your Code.

Comment: Unfortunately `startActivityForResult(...)` may not work with all SMS apps. As the OP is simply using an implict `Intent`, the user's default SMS app will be started - if it doesn't return a result then the original `Activity's` `onActivityResult(...)` method won't be called.

Comment: @Squonk exactly as evident from this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/3hjk-g-eaFU